# What's the priority of kernel bad block log?

Tags: kernel

We are considering transferring the following kernel bad block log to the syslog server. 
Could you tell me the priority of the kernel bad block? 
Currently the setting in `/etc/syslog.conf`, kernel is set to output debug messages to `/var/log/messages`.

```
Jan 17 22:13:14 xxx kernel: pid 19 (softdepflush), uid 0 inumber 24141 on /: bad block 
Jan 17 22:13:14 xxx kernel: bad block -4470673541826633732, ino 24141
```

`/etc/syslog.conf`

```
*.notice;local0.none;local1.none;local2.none;authpriv.none;kern.debug;mail.crit;news.err /var/log/messages 
local2.notice /var/log/messages
```

Comment: Could you indicate what you have tried so far? Since you know how to get the messages into /var/log/messages, I would have thought the only missing link is setting up a remote destination, which seems to be relatively easy to find instructions for. Are you facing a specific issue on having tried a few things?

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu 16.04 system I can see the priority of all messages in the kernel ring buffer with:

```
dmesg -x
```

You should be able to use that command on the system where you saw that log message in order to learn what its priority is.